# Automatically binding a model property if it is present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm not sure i know the exact terminology for what i want to do, so i'll just describe what i want, and hopefully someone will give me the answer or direct me to the right place...

I want some (maybe all) of the models on my site to inherit from `IGeneralSettings` -

```
public interface IGeneralSettings
{
    User CurrentUser { get; set; }
    UserSettings PersonalSettings { get; set; }
}
```

and if the current user is authenticated/logged in, I will check if the current controller's model is of a type that implements `IGeneralSettings`, and if it is, I will fill the data with the current user data.

I am using Windsor Castle as an IoC container.
I don't want to use the property bag for this.
I don't want to call a method that will do this in each action in each controller, I want this to be injected automatically each request - meaning this code will be written once.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend adding your CurrentUser and PersonalSettings objects to a base controller and populating it each request (if they are authenticated). Then you can access them in a custom model binder because you have access to the controller context.

Example of one way to do it:

### Base controller that your controllers inherit

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        //You can load the CurrentUser and Settings here
        CurrentUser = new User
        {
            Id = 1
        };

        PersonalSettings = new UserSettings
        {
            Id = 1
        };
    }

    public User CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public UserSettings PersonalSettings { get; set; }
}
```

### ModelBinder

```
public class ThingModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      {
        var model = (Thing)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var baseController = controllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        if (baseController != null)
        {
            model.CurrentUser = baseController.CurrentUser;
            model.PersonalSettings = baseController.PersonalSettings;
        }

        return model;
      }
}
```

### Add ModelBinder in Application_Start of Global.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Thing), new ThingModelBinder());
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Thing model)
    {
        //model has CurrentUser and PersonalSettings set 
        //without any values being posted. 
        //You can also access the values on the BaseController 
        //if you don't want to automatically bind it.

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean, Can you give me a more detailed example, or link to an article that will help ?

Comment: In regards to the base controller concept or the custom modelbinder?

Comment: I accepted the answer. Thanks for the thorough example. This wasn't 'exactly' what i was expecting, but i think it's the closest I will get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found in my last project:
Define a extension method for Controller, like:

```
public static Models.User GetUser(this Controller controller)
    {
        string name = controller.User.Identity.Name;
        string alias = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        string domain = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('\\') - 1);
        User user = User.ByAlias(alias);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new User();
            user.Name = controller.User.Identity.Name;
            user.Alias = alias;
            user.Domain = domain;
            user.Description = "Automatically registered";

            Guid userId = Models.User.Create(user, Guid.Empty);
            user = User.ByAlias(alias);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

That would not break your current class structure.

Comment: but this means i need to call this extension method in each controller, and this is not what i wanted...